# Need to create two ALB modules using single terraform

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I am new to terraform, I have a situation like need to deploy one source code into two different EC2.

Meaning i am creating module ALB. If I create single ALB module i am fine. When I try to attempt other ALB i am ruining issue and end up with “multiple certificate issue”

Can any one have example to create two ALb with different names using same certificates ?

below is the code snip for the reference:

```
module "alb" {
  namespace                           = terraform.workspace
  name                                = join("-", [local.name, "asg"])
  vpc_cidr_code                       = lookup(var.awsacct_cidr_code, var.environment)
  autoscaling                         = true
  internal                            = true
  autoscale_inst_type                 = "m5.large"
  autoscale_min_size                  = 2
  autoscale_max_size                  = 3
  certificate_arn                     = data.aws_acm_certificate.xxx.arn
  backend_lb_port                     = 9443
  backend_lb_protocol                 = "HTTPS"
  health_check_monitor_path           = "/"
  autoscale_health_check_grace_period = 600
  health_check_interval               = 300
  health_check_timeout                = 120
  health_check_matcher                = "200-499"
  stickiness_enabled                  = false
  tags                                = module.namespace.tags
  autoscale_user_data = templatefile("{path.module}/user-data.tmpl",
    {
      environment         = var.ENV_PROFILE,
      keyarn              = module.aws_ssl.certificate.arn
      commitid            = var.COMMIT_ID
      secret              = var.nodekey_secret[var.environment]
      bucketname          = var.deploy_bucket[var.environment]
      bucketobject        = local.name
      ally_application_id = var.ally_application_id
    }
  )
}

module "alb-jobs" {
  namespace                           = terraform.workspace
 name                                = join("-", [local.name1, "asg"])
  vpc_cidr_code                       = lookup(var.awsacct_cidr_code, var.environment)
  autoscaling                         = true
  internal                            = true
  autoscale_inst_type                 = "m5.large"
  autoscale_min_size                  = 1
  autoscale_max_size                  = 1
  certificate_arn                     = data.aws_acm_certificate.xxx.arn
  backend_lb_port                     = 9443
  backend_lb_protocol                 = "HTTPS"
  health_check_monitor_path           = "/"
  autoscale_health_check_grace_period = 600
  health_check_interval               = 300
  health_check_timeout                = 120
  health_check_matcher                = "200-499"
  stickiness_enabled                  = false
 tags                                = module.namespace.tags
  autoscale_user_data = templatefile("{path.module}/user-data-jobs.tmpl",
    {
      environment         = var.ENV_PROFILE,
      keyarn              = module.aws_ssl.certificate.arn
      commitid            = var.COMMIT_ID
      secret              = var.nodekey_secret[var.environment]
      bucketname          = var.deploy_bucket[var.environment]
      bucketobject        = local.name1
      ally_application_id = var.ally_application_id
    }
  )
}

Eg:

data "aws_acm_certificate" "xxx" {
  domain   = lookup(var.awsacct_domain, var.environment)
  statuses = ["ISSUED"]
}

variable.tf file

awsacct_domain = {
  default       = "*.dev.xxx.com"
  dev           = "*.dev.xxx.com"
  non-prod-dev  = "*.dev.xxx.com"
  qa            = "*.qa.xxx.com"
  cap           = "*.cap.xxx.com"
  psp           = "*.psp.xxx.com"
  prod          = "*.prod.xxx.com"
}

Getting Error:

Error: Multiple certificates for domain "*.dev.xxx.com" found in this region
229 on main.tf line 5, in data "aws_acm_certificate" "xxx":
230 5: data "aws_acm_certificate" "xxx" {
```

Please help me to understand more.

Thanks in advance,
Bala.

Comment: Have you tried to write any TF code yourself? Can you show it and explain why it does not work?

Comment: @Marcin: I have added code snip.  hope you can understand. please let me know your thoughts

Comment: You haven't explained what's wrong with the code? Any errors?

Comment: Getting Error:

Error: Multiple certificates for domain "*.dev.xxx.com" found in this region
229 on main.tf line 5, in data "aws_acm_certificate" "xxx":
230 5: data "aws_acm_certificate" "xxx" {

Comment: What is var.environment?

Comment: @Marcin:  i can see pipeline is giving till Error: Multiple certificates for domain "*.dev.xxx.com" found in this region
229 on main.tf line 5, in data "aws_acm_certificate" "xxx":
230 5: data "aws_acm_certificate" "xxx"

Comment: Is this your real code? How come modules don't have `source` attribute? Also where and how exactly are you creating multiple ALBs? You are not using any count nor for_each.

Comment: and yes, this is the real code. in the above i am using module "alb" and module alb-jobs are two different alb modules and giving unique name for each. but using same certs. is this any thing wrong using the above code.

Comment: Yes, you are using the same data source for both certificates it seems.

Comment: i have created other entry for data source like data "aws_acm_certificate" "yyyy"{ domain   = lookup(var.awsacct_domain_job, var.environment)
  statuses = ["ISSUED"]
} but still is same issue, instead of aws_acm_certificate can i use any other keyword or what would be other way ?

Comment: @BalakrishnaTirumalasetti Can you try adding `most_recent = true` to the data source?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done mistake in the above code, I am try to creating two entries for data source, hence I am getting multiple certificates error. When I try to reuse the data source, it’s started working fine. Thanks to every on to make me understand.

Answer (score 0):

The error message is quite clear. You have multiple certificates for that particular domain, so it cannot pick just one due to ambiguity. You may have to pass additional arguments to pick the specific certificate. Maybe you can try passing [certificate type](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/data-sources/acm_certificate#types) as well.

Or you can consider deleting the any unused certificate to remove ambiguity.

Comment: i have created other entry for data source like data "aws_acm_certificate" "yyyy"{ domain = lookup(var.awsacct_domain_job, var.environment) statuses = ["ISSUED"] } but still is same issue, instead of aws_acm_certificate can i use any other keyword or what would be other way ?

Comment: Did you try adding the types atribute? Look at the certifiates you have in your account/region and supply necessary atributes to pick the certificate accordingly.

Comment: i have try using data.aws_acm_certificate.amazon_issued.arn still i am getting same issue, are you referring the same ? if i understand wrongly correct me.

Comment: Please read-up on what atributes are with respect to resources and get your basics right.  Within the data "aws_acm_certificate" "xxx" block, you need to pass additional attributes such as 'types' to select the appropriate certificate. Check the documentation.

Comment: i tried with possible attributes, https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/data-sources/acm_certificate#types but still no luck.

Comment: Can you update the code above with types argument that you tried?